Error when trying to use generic UITableViewCell
I'm trying to make a reusable UITableView. I will pass in generics for item and UITableViewCell. However am having an error when I try to cast my cell to C and am not sure how else to fix this.

Member 'reusableLoadMoreTableView' cannot be used on value of type
'any SharedLoadMoreTableViewDelegate<T, C>'; consider using a generic
constraint instead

protocol SharedLoadMoreTableViewDelegate<T, C>
{
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype C: UITableViewCell
    
    func reusableLoadMoreTableView(configure cell: C, for item: T)
}


class ReusableLoadMoreTableView<T, C: UITableViewCell>: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{   
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private var items: [T] = []
    
    var delegate: (any SharedLoadMoreTableViewDelegate<T, C>)?
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
     {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! C
            
        if indexPath.row < items.count 
         {
            delegate?.reusableLoadMoreTableView(configure: cell, for: items[indexPath.row])
         }
            
           return cell
      }
    
  }


I don't get any error using your code

Replacing any with some on the delegate declaration solves the issue in Swift 5. var delegate: (some SharedLoadMoreTableViewDelegate<T, C>)?.

As the compiler suggests, you should consider SharedLoadMoreTableViewDelegate as a generic constraint instead of a type
protocol SharedLoadMoreTableViewDelegate<T, C>
{
    associatedtype T
    associatedtype C: UITableViewCell
    
    func reusableLoadMoreTableView(configure cell: C, for item: T)
}


class ReusableLoadMoreTableView<LoadMoreT: SharedLoadMoreTableViewDelegate>: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        0
    }
    
    private let tableView = UITableView()
    private var items: [LoadMoreT.T] = []
    
    var delegate: LoadMoreT?
    
     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
     {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"CustomTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! LoadMoreT.C
            
        if indexPath.row < items.count
         {
            delegate?.reusableLoadMoreTableView(configure: cell, for: items[indexPath.row])
         }
            
           return cell
      }
    
  }

Your code is also not compiling in the old version of swift that you are using. Since the implementation of SE-0352, it will compile properly. My advice is to update your swift version by updating XCode version or installing a newer swift installation onto your machine to match or exceed Swift 5.7
